# Docker build from source fails

Tags: docker

After git clone from dotcloud/docker

```
cd docker
sudo make VERBOSE=1

Fetching https://net/http/cookiejar?go-get=1
https fetch failed
**
 unrecognized import path "net/http/cookiejar"
```

Can any one please tell me what should i be looking at. I have Go 1.1 installed. The reason i wanted to build docker from src it to remove sys_rawio from lxc.cap.drop. I needed to make CUDA work with lxc containers. I was able to compile cuda code but while running it. I keep getting driver related error that says Operation not permitted.

Comment: Are you sure you have go1.1? This error is typically go1.0.x. Double check your path and try without makefile: `cd docker/docker; go build; ./docker -d& ./docker version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker can now be used to build docker and is the recommended (and only supported) method, see:

https://docs.docker.com/project/set-up-dev-env/

Answer (score 2):

Installed Go from https://go.googlecode.com/files/go1.1.1.linux-amd64.tar.gz

As suggested by user creack in above comments.
cd docker/docker; go build; ./docker -d& ./docker version

I have docker build successfully now.