# Need docker to build docker?

Tags: docker

I download the [docker](https://github.com/docker/docker) and want to compile it from the source code:

```
[root@localhost docker-1.5.0]# make
mkdir bundles
docker build -t "docker" .
/bin/sh: docker: command not found
make: *** [build] Error 127
```

Per my understanding, if I want to compile `docker`, I need to get a `docker` firstly. Is it right? If it is true, how does the first `docker` come?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Docker build from source fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069635/docker-build-from-source-fails)

Comment: Basically, you need to [install it first](http://docs.docker.com/installation/), then you use it to build itself. Starting with only the source isn't supported at this point.

Comment: @aruisdante: If "`Starting with only the source isn't support at this point`", how does the first `docker` come?

Comment: Read the installation instructions I linked to. You install it as appropriate for your system. You never need to build docker from source unless you're modifying it for some reason.

Comment: @NanXiao presumably the first Docker wasn't built using Docker :) However, an older version of Docker can be used to build a newer version of Docker, pretty much analogous to compiler bootstrapping.

Answer (score 0):

yum or apt-get install docker-io will install the docker-io 
then you build it from source and it replace the existing docker or set your path to point to the new docker.

Answer (score 0):

You must have Docker to build Docker only because that's what the Docker guys thought would be the most convenient.

Of course, there is a way to compile the Docker source without having Docker installed on your machine; but then - you will have to have on your machine all the compilation tools and dependencies needed for the compilation.
So, the Docker team "dockerized" the compilation process. Namely, they used Docker itself, and what it is intended to do, also for the compilation of the Docker source.